# React Native Skia Base64 Image Not Showing on Android but works on iOS

Tags: react-native

[image]

```
// Did some investigation and useImage() returns null on Android that's why image is not showing.


const image = useImage(base64); // null
```

More investigation details here:
https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia/issues/283

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. I used this to convert base64 image to Uint8Array.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-js

```
import { toByteArray } from 'base64-js';

const buffer = toByteArray(base64);
const image = useImage(buffer);

  return (
    <Canvas style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Image x={0} y={0} width={100} height={100} image={image} />
    </Canvas>
  );
```